# Is it possible to achieve something like "global" Hooks?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, hook

I know how to enable Server side hooks in Tortoise SVN, but the problem is that I want to have hooks which are like *"global"*, e.g. every repository on the server should use the global hooks.

I have a hook which has to be included in every repository - I could now copy the hook by hand in every repository, but I want to know if it's possible to declare something like a global hook, so that there is just one place where the hook exists.

Any suggestions? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually hooks can only be defined *per repository*.

What I do to handle the same thing that you want to achieve is the following:

- I have a place where I store the hook scripts that I want global
- I've then set up a scheduled task that will copy all these scripts to every repository if they are not there already

Using this solution, I can easily change a hook script and update it everywhere, and whenever I create a new repository all the needed hooks will be added to it.

I've used this indifferently on Linux or Windows server.

Comment: Thank you very much for letting me know that it is (sadly) not possible the global way! Scripting would have been my next step, too. ;-) Thanks!

Comment: of course you could have a hook script in each repo that simply runs a script that is stored elsewhere....